# How can I better protect my LAN from Internet Hackers

Tags: firewalls

My computer is connected to my Netgear router which is also the switch for my network, this in turn is connected to my cable modem which is just a bridging device.

My router is blocking scans and fragmentation attacks but I believe its processor and RAM is getting hammered doing so because my LAN speed is very slow both wired and wireless and on multiple machines.

Would adding a hardware firewall between my ISP bridge and my Router help or is there a better solution to dealing with these attacks?

Comment: Your router is already has a firewal likely made by the same people that you would purchase the firewall from.

Comment: Yes my router does have a firewall but since its processing the attacks it is going slow which slows my LAN down.

Comment: If this is a connection in your home, its unlikely the "attacks" that is slowing your LAN network/  Your ISP already has a firewall better then anything you could purchase.  Furthermore the type of hardware you would required is epensive, hardware firewalls, are not something you go to your local electronic store and buy.

Comment: I recommend you consult your ISP to identify source of attack and block it at first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a second firewall in front of your current one would offload some of the processing of scans/probes/attacks and free up CPU cycles on your Netgear router/switch/AP. Just get another Netgear and configure the two devices to talk to each other.

**BUT**, I do not have high hopes that this will accomplish what you seek. It is unlikely that your Netgear is so overwhelmed that it cannot properly handle legitimate traffic. Look to see what the actual problem might be. Too many machines communicating at once? Line noise/interference? Infected machines sending bot traffic?

Set up Wireshark on one of your wired machines and on a wireless machine and see what is going on on the line.

Comment: If you add another netgear in front of the old one how is that going to fix the issue?  It's going to repeat the same issue as well as adding another layer of natting adding to the processing going on in the netgear router.

Comment: I never did say that the extra device would fix the overall problem, just that it resolves the OP's stated issue: external probes tying up resources on the external firewall. Yes, the extra device will add latency and other delays. The OP was concerned about LAN speed, not Internet speed, in which case, NATting is not an issue.

Comment: Yes my internal network is the issue, I am getting DDOSD at certain times of the day that is when my LAN goes really slow at less than 4MB transfer speeds on a gigabit network. I have contacted my ISP to get them to filter the traffic and I will add a dedicated switch for my LAN.